# User defined Jacobian pattern in MATLAB's lsqnonlin being ignored

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I am using MATLAB's [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) function, and I am attempting to set a user-defined Jacboian *pattern* via the option `JacobPattern`. I set a preference for the `trust-region-reflective` algorithm to be used, and the `output` from `lsqnonlin` indicates that this was indeed the algorithm used by the solver (required for the use of the `JacobPattern` option).

The problem I am finding is that if my `JacobPattern` is too sparse (e.g. just a few rows of ones in a 500x500 Jacobian), it is being ignored by the solver and the full Jacobian is being computed instead.

This behaviour is not documented; can anyone shed any further light on it? I would like to be able to force the solver to use my `JacobPattern` no matter how absurdly sparse it is, or how shallow a gradient is found with it.

---

**Update:**

I have done some more experiments, and it appears the Jacobian is only recomputed if there are any all-zero *rows* in the Jacobian pattern. Any number of all-zero columns are ok, as long as at there is at least one '1' in each row. Although this helps to avoid the problem, the question still remains --- why does the solver require each dependent variable to have an associated gradient? In any case,  I would expect the ignoring of a user-defined option to be at least worthy of a warning...

Comment: How sparse does your matrix have to be before matlab tries to recalculate?

Comment: Ok thanks, your question has shed some more light on the issue - I will update the question above accordingly.

Comment: Could you give the full function call, or better yet a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the following:

If you take a look at what the jacobian actually means, you'll see that all-zero rows mean that the corresponding function (part of the vector function defined) is independent of any variable. It is thus completely pointless adding it to the optimization.

As for purposefully handing a wrong Jacobian to the algorithm,
why would you want to do that?